# How to call a webservice with SOAP request using POST method in Node js

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');


var input = fs.readFileSync('./test.xml', {
    encoding: 'utf8'
});

var http = require('http');
//var data = JSON.stringify(

var options = {
    host: 'dneonline.com',
    port: '80',
    path: '/calculator.asmx',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length': input.length
    }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    var msg = '';

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        msg += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});
```